# How Can Pass QImage to qml without ImageProvider?

Tags: qt, qml, qimage

I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887675/loading-from-byte-array-to-image-in-qml/55901771#55901771) to read an image from SQL dataBase (the image saved in dataBase as BLOB) and pass it to qml but I get this error :
**QML Image: Error decoding: data:image/png;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCg==: Unsupported image format**

how can I fix this error?

cpp:

```
void MainWindow::saveToDatabase(QQuickItem *imageObj) {

  QSharedPointer<const QQuickItemGrabResult> grabResult =
      imageObj->grabToImage();
  connect(grabResult.data(), &QQuickItemGrabResult::ready, [=]() {
    QImage img(grabResult->image());
    QByteArray imageArray;
    QBuffer buffer(&imageArray);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img.save(&buffer, "PNG");
    dbModify->dbinsertRecords(imageArray);
  });
}


QString MainWindow::convertToImage(int pos) {
       //SelectLastData define as QVariantList in header
        QString base64 =
            QString::fromUtf8(SelectLastData[pos].toByteArray().toBase64().data());
        return QString("data:image/png;base64,") + base64;
    }
```

qml:

```
onClicked: {
     stackView.push("qrc:/imagePage.qml",  {"url" : mainWindow.convertToImage(9)})
           }
```

imagePage.qml:

```
Page {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    property alias url: screenshoot.source
    Rectangle {
  Image {
         id: screenshoot
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you save the image? It looks like you didn't save it in the PNG format. Why don't you want to use an ImageProvider?

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the post and added the function saveToDatabase , I save it as PNG in database

Comment: 1. Please provide a [mre] 2.  Why don't you want to use an ImageProvider?

Comment: Save as base64 in db: `dbModify->dbinsertRecords(imageArray.toBase64());` and `QString::fromUtf8(SelectLastData[pos].toByteArray().data());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 data in the error message: `"77+9UE5HDQoaCg=="` corresponds to the bytes `ef bf bd 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a` which includes 3 bytes that shouldn't be there for a PNG header (it should start with `89 50 4e 47`) and that indicates that the data is truncated, which means the data is read as a null terminated string instead of a binary blob (9th byte of a PNG file is usually a null character).

That is probably because you are passing a `char*` to `QVariant` instead of a `QByteArray` when you initialize the `QVariantList`.

Basically, when you pass a `char*` as a parameter to its constructor or `setValue`, `QVariant` interprets it as a null terminated UTF-8 string and stores it natively as a `QString`, then, when you call `toByteArray` it converts it to UTF-8. The 2 conversions from and to UTF-8 can cause corruption on binary data.

If you create an intermediate `QByteArray` variable and use it directly to initialize the `QVariant`, it will be stored as `QByteArray` and no conversion will occur when you'll call `toByteArray`.